# Update Datepicker UI javascript file with SELECT from SQL table?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, datepicker, gaps-and-islands

[image: Check SQL Table]

This is the structure of SQL table called "calende_bookings".

```
  TABLE `calende_bookings`
     - `id`,
     - `id_item`,
     - `the_date`,
     - `id_state`,
     - `id_booking`,
     - PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
```

The goal is to get reservation dates which already existing in database and update Datepicker ui which will disable those date ranges in Datapicker, so users will not be able to pick them when they made reservations. Start date is always afternoon so id_state=3 is always start date (from: in outcome case), and date with last id_state=1 before date with id_state=2 is always last date (to: in outcome case). Two items will be displayed seperetely so I need the thing for one of them. This need to be outcome (dynamic dates).

```
var disabledArrFromTo = [ 
  { "from": "21-06-2021", "to": "26-06-2021" },
  { "from": "12-08-2021", "to": "14-08-2021" },
  { "from": .....} 
]
```

This is my Datepicker code who actually work fine but when I wrote disabled date-ranges manualy. I used many example with simple dates, so no dates ranges, it disabled dates in Datapicker, but entire script stop with prices calculation.

```
$(window).load(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {

// An array of objects containing disabled date ranges
var disabledArrFromTo = [ { "from": "1-08-2021", "to": "19-08-2021" }, { "from": "23-08-2021", "to": "9-09-2021" } ];

$("#fromto").datepicker({
 beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //console.log(date);

        // For each calendar date, check if it is within a disabled range.
        for(i=0;i<disabledArrFromTo.length;i++){
            // Get each from/to ranges
            var From = disabledArrFromTo[i].from.split("-");
            var To = disabledArrFromTo[i].to.split("-");
            // Format them as dates : Year, Month (zero-based), Date
            var FromDate = new Date(From[2],From[1]-1,From[0]);
            var ToDate = new Date(To[2],To[1]-1,To[0]);

            // Set a flag to be used when found
            var found=false;
            // Compare date
            if(date>=FromDate && date<=ToDate){
                found=true;
                return [false, "red"]; // Return false (disabled) and the "red" class.
            }
        }
        
        //At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
        if(!found){
            return [true, "blue"]; // Return true (Not disabled) and no class.
        }
    },
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_h.png",
    buttonText: "Arrival",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    altField: "#fromto",
    altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    gotoCurrent:  true,
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    showOn: 'both',
    yearRange: "-0:+2",
    minDate: "+1D",
    setDate: "+1",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (startDate, inst) {
            var date = startDate.split("-");
            $('#dd').val(date[0]);
            $('#md').val(date[1]);
            $('#yd').val(date[2]);
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3);
            }
            $("#tofrom").datepicker("option","minDate", date)
             var startDate = new Date(parseInt($('#yd').val(),10),parseInt($('#md').val(),10)-1,parseInt($('#dd').val(),10));
            $('.dirko').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd. mm. yy', new Date(startDate)));
            $('.ddirko').text($.datepicker.formatDate('D dd MM yy', new Date(startDate)));
        }

 });


  $("#tofrom").datepicker({
 beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //console.log(date);

        // For each calendar date, check if it is within a disabled range.
        for(i=0;i<disabledArrFromTo.length;i++){
            // Get each from/to ranges
            var From = disabledArrFromTo[i].from.split("-");
            var To = disabledArrFromTo[i].to.split("-");
            // Format them as dates : Year, Month (zero-based), Date
            var FromDate = new Date(From[2],From[1]-1,From[0]);
            var ToDate = new Date(To[2],To[1]-1,To[0]);

            // Set a flag to be used when found
            var found=false;
            // Compare date
            if(date>=FromDate && date<=ToDate){
                found=true;
                return [false, "red"]; // Return false (disabled) and the "red" class.
            }
        }
        
        //At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
        if(!found){
            return [true, ""]; // Return true (Not disabled) and no class.
        }
    },


    buttonImage: "images/calendar_h.png",
    buttonText: "Departure",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    altField: "#tofrom",
    altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    gotoCurrent:  true,
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    showOn: 'both',
    yearRange: "-0:+2",
    minDate: "+1D",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (endDate, inst) {
            var eDates = endDate.split("-");
            $('#dr').val(eDates[0]);
            $('#mr').val(eDates[1]);
            $('#yr').val(eDates[2]);
            var endDate = new Date(parseInt($('#yr').val(),10),parseInt($('#mr').val(),10)-1,parseInt($('#dr').val(),10));          
            $('.cirko').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd. mm. yy', new Date(endDate)));
            $('.ccirko').text($.datepicker.formatDate('D dd MM yy', new Date(endDate)));
    }
    
 });


 });
```

I extracted dates from databese table in PHP for future dates with this ...

```sql
/*ITEM 1*/
SELECT 
  id_item,
  id_state,
  id_date,
DATE_FORMAT (the_date, "%e-%m-%Y") AS from_the_date 
FROM calende_bookings
WHERE the_date > now()
  AND id_item = 1
  AND (id_state = 3 || id_state = 1)
ORDER by the_date ASC
```

My test PHP file connection with database.

```
<?php
$servername = "********";
$username = "***********";
$password = "***********";
$dbname = "***********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo 'var disabledArrFromTo = [';


$sql = 'SELECT 
id_item, 
id_state, 
the_date, 
DATE_FORMAT (the_date, "%e-%m-%Y") AS from_the_date 
FROM calende_bookings 
WHERE the_date > now() 
AND id_item = 1 
AND (id_state = 3 
|| id_state = 1) 
ORDER by the_date ASC';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '"'. $row['from_the_date'] . '",';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

        echo '"31-12-2076"];';

$conn->close();
?>
```

Outcome look like this:

```
var disabledArrFromTo = ["25-06-2021","26-06-2021","31-12-2076"];
```

and I need something like this (startdate = date with item_state = 3 and enddate is last item_state = 1 before item_state = 2, check image on the top of the post):

```
var disabledArrFromTo = [ 
  { "from": "21-06-2021", "to": "26-06-2021" },
  { "from": "12-08-2021", "to": "14-08-2021" },
  { "from": .....} 
]
```

Comment: It would be better to focus on single problem in a question, because it's hard to get what the issues you have. Can you manage the disabling part of task? If so, you can easily remove JS part of a question. Did you stuck with identifying of consecutive dates? So you can leave only short introduction into task context and focus only on SQL part. For SQL questions you should [tag your DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to make answers more useful.

Comment: Also please add input data in tabular text format, not as image. Images cannot be reused to create some input for answer query. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) is an explanation, why it is important for future readers. And use the same format for input and desired results: in your question input is tabular, but result is JSON, where JSON does not matter (SQL client will serialize results for you). It takes time to map source and target instead of focusing on real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Prepare an array with all disabled dates

var disabledDates =['01/01/2020', '02/02/2020'];

function checkDayAvailable(day) {
var fDay=day.getDate() + '/'+ (day.getMonth()+1) + "/" + day.getFullYear();
return inArray(fDay, disabled Dates)
}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: checkDayAvailable });

Sorry,  I'm on my phone, maybe I've made some syntax errors

So, for bringing data from db and update the JS array you can do it two ways:

Insert php code in you page. This code will get data from db and then echo it into JS code;
This may look like:

```
<?php
//.....
//.....
$serverName = "your_server_name";
$connectionString = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionString );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar_bookings";
$res = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $res === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$r="'";
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $r.=$row['the_date']."',";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $res);
$r=substr($r, 0, -1);

?>

<script language="javascript">
var var disabledDates =[<?php=$r ?>];
```

By using an external service called by an ajax call. In this case you will need an external file which contains all php code. For example (supposing you are using jquery in your page):
php file (let's call it server.php) will look like:

```
<?php 
    $serverName = "your_server_name";
    $connectionString = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionString );
    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar_bookings";
    $res = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $res === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
    $r=[];
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          $r[]=$row['the_date'];
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $res);
    exit json_encode($r);
    ?>
```

your js code (supposing you are using jquery, just for simplyfing):

```
....
<script>
  $.post(
   '/server.php',
   {},
   function(data){
     try {
       var disabledDates = JSON.parse(data);
       //now do whatever you need with
    } catch(e){
       console.warn(e); 
   }
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for replay. I already have Datapicker UI working well and disable those dates if I write manually those dates in Java Script file of Datepicker. I have them all in database too because I have other script which I made reservation from admin area. So idea is to pick them from database table and disable dates in Datapicker UI which I used in Ajax form. That part I already have running well. So I need part before that, from database to that line which will insert those dates from database table into "var disabledArrFromTo" line, like StartDate (from) and EndDate (to).

Comment: what kind of database? which is the type of 'the_date' field?

Comment: It is SQL database. About field "the_date", I don't understand the question. This all what I have for that field: `the_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',

Comment: Hello Arian. Thank you for those examples, but ... Datapicker example did not worked at all. First example of php, did not work either, I tried many times without success to even get out any result with php. Never came to java part. I have my own primitive php example (without substring at the end) which pull out single occupied dates from database and it list me all what I need but for some unknown reason my datepicker only work with ranges outcome, when I use single dates outcome in Datepicker (BeforeShowDay), it disable dates in Datepicker, but also it disable entire script. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use it as it, you should adapt it to your environment, database, etc. It looks pretty easy for me.

Comment: I was not use it as it is, separate php file, connection with database, and failed. Than I found few errors, but I was gave up when I saw that outcome is one single date, like you are able to see, I have that code working, I need date range with start and end dates. If it is "easy", I am ready to write SOLVED as fast as anybody post real working solution (php database range-dates outcome and than that outcome packed inside simple script codes ). Everything needed for that solution is in first post, except few lines of solution.